# How to use grooupby properly with previous filter

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe looks like this

```
       Seats  Saw_Flop WTSD WMSD WWSF
0  _M3M3N7O_         0   No   No   No
1   aladin03         0   No   No  Yes
2   aladin03         1   No   No  Yes
3   aladin03         0   No   No   No
4   aladin03         0   No   No   No
5   aladin03         0   No   No   No
6   aladin03         1   No   No   No
7  kingbel81         0   No   No   No
8  kingbel81         1   No   No   No
9  kingbel81         1   No   No  Yes
```

What i want to do is groupby seats and calculate when Yes appear in columns WMSD, WWSF and WTSD but only for rows where Saw_Flop == 1.
What i have done is:

```
dfWTSD = df2[df2['Saw_Flop'] == 1].groupby('Seats').WTSD.value_counts().groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x/x.sum()*100).loc(axis=0)[slice(None), 'Yes'].reset_index(drop=True, level=1).reset_index(name = 'WTSD%')
dfWWSF = df2[df2['Saw_Flop'] == 1].groupby('Seats').WWSF.value_counts().groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x/x.sum()*100).loc(axis=0)[slice(None), 'Yes'].reset_index(drop=True, level=1).reset_index(name = 'WWSF%')
dfWMSD = df2[df2['Saw_Flop'] == 1].groupby('Seats').WMSD.value_counts().groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x/x.sum()*100).loc(axis=0)[slice(None), 'Yes'].reset_index(drop=True, level=1).reset_index(name = 'WMSD%')
```

So first i filtered data for Saw_Flop == 1 and then groupby to calculate % of Yes appearing. 
I dont know if my logic is correct because i recieved average % like 20 but should be around 40-45.

Can u tell me if my way to calculate this is correct and show another way to do groupby?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your solution working nice if need percentages from filtered rows only.

You can simplify it by compare valeus to mask and get `mean`:

```
mask = df2['Saw_Flop'] == 1
cols = ['WTSD','WMSD','WWSF']
df = df2.loc[mask, cols].eq('Yes').groupby(df2['Seats']).mean().mul(100).add_suffix('%')
print (df)
           WTSD%  WMSD%  WWSF%
Seats                         
aladin03     0.0    0.0   50.0
kingbel81    0.0    0.0   50.0
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df2.loc[mask, cols].eq('Yes'))
    WTSD   WMSD   WWSF
2  False  False   True
6  False  False  False
8  False  False  False
9  False  False   True
```

But if need to count how many filtered values from all values of columns:

```
m1 = df2['Saw_Flop'] == 1
cols = ['WTSD','WMSD','WWSF']
m2 = df2[cols] == 'Yes'

mask = m2.mul(m1, axis=0)
df = mask.groupby(df2['Seats']).mean().mul(100).add_suffix('%')
print (df)
           WTSD%  WMSD%      WWSF%
Seats                             
_M3M3N7O_    0.0    0.0   0.000000
aladin03     0.0    0.0  16.666667
kingbel81    0.0    0.0  33.333333
```

**Detail**:

```
print (mask)
    WTSD   WMSD   WWSF
0  False  False  False
1  False  False  False
2  False  False   True
3  False  False  False
4  False  False  False
5  False  False  False
6  False  False  False
7  False  False  False
8  False  False  False
9  False  False   True
```